# Not able to bind click event in kendo mvvm row template

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid with a button to remove the current item and for that grid I have a row template. Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <table class="fixed-table-width"
            data-role="grid"
            data-bind="source: data"
            data-scrollable="false"
            data-row-template="row-template">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="row-template">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: item"></span></td>
        <td><button class="link" data-bind="click: remove"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove</button></br ></td>
    </tr>
    </script>
```

And that is my model:

```
function AddItemComponent($scope) {
    if ($scope === null || $scope === undefined) throw new Error("Unknown scope, please provide the scope");

    var self = this;

    self.itemModel = {
        item: "Item to Remove",
        remove: function(i) {
            self.viewModel.items = self.viewModel.items.splice(i);
        }
    };
    self.viewModel = kendo.observable({
        items: []
    });

    self.viewModel.items.push(self.itemModel);
};
```

But when I open the modal with this HTML, I get the following error:

> kendo.binder.min.js?cdv=40:25 Uncaught TypeError: t.get is not a function(…)

If I remove the **data-bind** from the click event, there is no error and it just works fine, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is better done with a commands column

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.command

```
data-columns="[{ field: 'item' }, { command: 'destroy' }]"
```

You don't neeed a row template anymore.

If you don't want to do this, try to wrap your itemModel in an observable, as get() is a method from kendo.data.ObservableObject

```
self.itemModel = kendo.observable({
    item: "Item to Remove",
    remove: function(i) {
        self.viewModel.items = self.viewModel.items.splice(i);
    }
});
```